# Ubuntu 14.04.2 new install - boot on recovery mode only

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, intel-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 14.02 on an old HP 540J with a dual boot Windows XP.
The PC is a Pentium 4 with 2.8Gig of RAM.

When I try to boot on Ubuntu from the GRU I get a black/orange page but it freezes and does not complete boot.

I am able to boot on recovery mode, but pages update very slowly on the screen (much slower than with Windows XP mode).

I am wondering whether the problem is related to the graphics card or some missing drives.

Any hint on how to solve this problem would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Bookmarked to get responses...

Comment: guest-bdrM1s@PC-filles:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a08
 Kernel modules: i915
--
02:04.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV100 [Radeon 7000 / Radeon VE]
 Subsystem: VISIONTEK Device 0280
 Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb